# Calculating AUC on Random Forest Model in R

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, auc

I'm trying to calculate AUC on my two models Random Forest and Naive Bayes
but getting the same error ""$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" .
Would you have some ideas please ?

Background: Target variable "Diagnosis" is non-numerical with values B and M

Here is sample code for RF model

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method="cv",number = 5,preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.4),classProbs = TRUE,summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

wdbc_model_rf <- train(Diagnosis~.,train_wdbc,method="ranger",metric="ROC",preProcess = c('center', 'scale'),trControl=fitControl)
```

Comment: If you turn the Diagnosis variable into a dummy variable (say B is 1 and M is 0) are you still getting an error?

Comment: hi Phil, yes that would solve an issue but Random Forest requires character type value for my target variable. Below is rest of the code

wdbc_predicions_rf <- predict(wdbc_model_rf, test_wdbc)
confusionMatrix(wdbc_predicions_rf,as.factor(test_wdbc$Diagnosis),positive = "M")

So when I want to get ROC curve and AUC using below code, an error shows up

wdbc_roc_rf <- roc(wdbc_predicions_auc$Diagnosis, wdbc_predicions_rf$preds)
wdbc_roc$auc

Happy to swap characters to numbers but how would I do it without breaking RF model ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of R code that works. Please note: your interest in ROC implies there are only two classes.

```
Predict <- function(class_obj, newdata, Param) {

if(Param$method == 'RF') {
    Predicted_Probs         <- predict(class_obj, newdata = newdata, type = 'prob')
} else if(Param$method == 'GBM') {
    Predicted_Probs         <- predict(class_obj, newdata = newdata, type = 'response', n.trees = Param$n.trees)[,,1]
} else if(Param$method == 'SVM') {
    Predicted_Probs         <- predict(class_obj, newdata = newdata, type = 'probabilities')
} else if(Param$method == 'logit') {
    Predicted_Probs         <- predict(class_obj, newdata = newdata, type = 'response')
    Predicted_Probs         <- cbind(1 - Predicted_Probs, Predicted_Probs)
} else { 
    cat('\nPredict(): unknown classification method.')
}

Predicted_Probs[,2]

}
```

@@@

```
AUC <- function(Truth, Predicted_Probs) {

###########################################################################################################
# SETTINGS

d_Prob              <- 0.01

###########################################################################################################
# CALCULATIONS

Prob_Grid               <- seq(1, 0, -d_Prob)
NP                  <- length(Prob_Grid)
True_Positive_Rate      <- c()
False_Positive_Rate     <- c()

for(Prob_Threshold in Prob_Grid) {
    Forecast                <- as.factor( c(0, 1, 1 * (Predicted_Probs >= Prob_Threshold)) )
    levels(Forecast)            <- c('0', '1')
    Forecast                <- Forecast[-c(1,2)]
    Table               <- xtabs(~Truth + Forecast)
    False_Positive_Rate     <- c(False_Positive_Rate, Table[1,2] / (Table[1,1] + Table[1,2]))
    True_Positive_Rate      <- c(True_Positive_Rate, Table[2,2] / (Table[2,1] + Table[2,2]))
}

AUC                 <- 0

for(i in 2:NP) {
    AUC                 <- AUC + True_Positive_Rate[i] * (False_Positive_Rate[i] - False_Positive_Rate[i-1])
}

AUC

}
```

Please note: the code is quite generic and can be applied to many methods, like [support vector machines](http://stanfordphd.com/SVM.html), [gradient boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting), [random forests](http://stanfordphd.com/RandomForest.html), etc. Hopefully, it is straightforward to modify the code to your needs.

Comment: hi Stans,

Thanks, but it doesn't work for me for some reason. Is there any way I could easily swap Diagnosis output to numerical ? Tried as.matrix(Diagnosis) but it didn't work 


'wdbc_roc_rf <- roc(wdbc_predicions_auc$Diagnosis, wdbc_predicions_rf$preds) wdbc_roc$auc'

Comment: AUC is defined only in the classification setting. So your dependent variable must be categorical. You are solving a classification problem, not a regression problem. If your dependent variable is a factor with levels "0" and "1", my code will work.